# Set Kendo Grid JSP to take remainder space

Tags: html, css, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using JSP Wrapper version of Kendo UI.

Currently, I have a fixed height for my grid:

```
<kendo:grid name="SUBUL_02_GRID" pageable="true" resizable="true" 
            sortable="true" height="800">
```

I'd like the grid to take the remainder space of my page, but setting height="100%" doesn't work. The height is set to some arbitrarily value that's smaller than 50% of the page.

I'm not sure if this matters but I also have virtual scrolling enabled

```
<kendo:grid-scrollable virtual="true" />
```

How do I make the grid take remainder of the space?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **dataBound** event of the Grid and set the height programatically with JavaScript 
e.g.

```
function onGridDataBound() {

        this.element.find('.k-grid-content').height(this.tbody.height());
        this.virtualScrollable.refresh();

}
```

Comment: There are two problems with the solution you have given me. One is I want the grid to take the remainder of the space even if there aren't enough items to fill the space with. Another is that if there are too many items in the grid, it stretches the grid too far beyond the remainder of the page space.

Comment: Actually, what I'm seeing seems like the default behavior of the grid, so maybe this isn't working properly? It is calling the function on databound event though..